# Why is GCC not able to compile file on arm64 Raspbian Bullseye?

Tags: c, 64-bit

I tried to run a simple program with  `gcc` on my Raspbian 64bit on Pi 4.

Is there something wrong with my `gcc` installation?

```
pi@RPi64: $ cat h.c
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
  printf ("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}

pi@RPi64: $ gcc -o h h.c
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/libgcc_s.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

pi@RPi64: $ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 10.2.1-6' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-10/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-10 --program-prefix=aarch64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=aarch64-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-mutex
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up `apt remove`ing some packages analog to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/798185/how-to-restore-usr-lib-gcc) answer I found after posting the question.

After

```
apt remove gcc
apt remove build-essential
```

I still had the problematic file in `ls /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/10` so I also did

```
libstdc++-10-dev:arm64
libgcc-10-dev:arm64
```

and then `apt autoremove` which removed some extra packages.

Finally, `apt install build-essential` installed all the packages and I was able to run `cpp` again. Not sure what made the difference, the date of the re-installed problematic file is the same.

Comment: The file probably got corrupted somehow.    Probably could have used `dpkg -S` to determine what package it was from and then `apt install --reinstall` on that package.  Or, `dpkg -V package` to verify that the package is not corrupt.

Comment: Thanks for the information. `dpkg -V` would have indeed been interesting to know.